# What's the purpose of use_tempaddr=1 kernel parameter?

Tags: debian, kernel, ipv6, sysctl

Reading `sysctl` docs, I found the following:

```
use_tempaddr - INTEGER
    Preference for Privacy Extensions (RFC3041).
      <= 0 : disable Privacy Extensions
      == 1 : enable Privacy Extensions, but prefer public
             addresses over temporary addresses.
      >  1 : enable Privacy Extensions and prefer temporary
             addresses over public addresses.
    Default:  0 (for most devices)
         -1 (for point-to-point devices and loopback devices)
```

So, when I set the `use_tempaddr` parameter to `0` , the Privacy Extensions are disabled, which means no temp addresses are used. When set to `2` , the Privacy Extension are enabled, and hence temp addresses are used. But when I set `use_tempaddr` to `1` the Privacy Extension are enabled but the temp addresses aren't used... So what's the purpose of having the three options, when only two of them make sense? What's the use case for `use_tempaddr` set to `1` ?

Comment: you'll probably get some answers with rationalizations for that -- but the long and short of it is that it **makes no sense**, just like having ipv6 addresses generated from the MAC in the 1st place or keeping the MAC-generated address around ("preferred" or not) when using privacy extensions. You should look into using [rfc7217](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7217) instead.

Comment: from a strictly technical point of view, notice that an application can bind an outgoing socket to any address set on an interface -- the "preferred" option only tells the kernel which local address to use when the app doesn't bind the socket explicitly.

Comment: Having the original IPv6 addr makes sense -- ppl from the net can connect to you and they always can connect using the same addr, so you don't have to give it to them each time when you're using Privacy Extensions.

Comment: there are such things like dynamic dns ;-)

Comment: Why to use it when it works OOTB?

Comment: That only works if you have a static prefix assigned to you (in which case you're better off using DHCPv6). Otherwise the mac-generated tail of your IPv6 address is only useful to trackers and other lowlife. In case my preferred/bind comment wasn't clear, setting `use_tempaddr=2` does **not** guarantee that a program will not keep using the mac-generated address for its outgoing connections.

Answer (score 3):

Setting it to 1 is one way to support a situation where some applications prefer ever-changing addresses and others prefer a long-lived address.

For example, if you use SSH, an RDP client and a web browser on the same laptop, you might want long-lived addresses for RDP and SSH (because both of those can use TCP connections that stay open for many hours or even days) and ever-changing addresses for the web browser (because of tracking concerns).

There are several ways to support this scenario. One of them is to set use_tempaddr to 1 and write special code to choose source address in the web browser. (I've seen such code, I think in an android app. I was puzzled by it. Didn't understand the point yet.)

There are other ways to achieve the same goal. But if you think that the kernel should let userspace maintainers decide which way is the best, then makes sense for the kernel to allow tempaddr=1.